# Hydration failed and window is not defined in NEXT 13 JS using React-leaflet

Tags: next.js13, react-leaflet

I am getting a ***Window is not defined*** error in Next.js 13 while using React-Leaflet. I tried using dynamic imports to solved that problem, and it successfully solved the ***Window is not defined*** error.

However, a new error has came in that place. The following error messages are:

1.Error: 

Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in

.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

2. Error: **There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.**

This is Map Component

`Map component`

```
"use client"
import { MapContainer, useMap, GeoJSON , Marker, Popup} from 'react-leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
import { TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Icon } from 'leaflet';

interface Props {
    height: string 
    width: string
    coordinateList?: any
  }

  export default function CoordinateMap({ height , width }: Props ): JSX.Element {  


    return (
    <MapContainer dragging={false} style={{ height: height, width: width }} scrollWheelZoom={false} zoomControl={false} center={[28.3949, 84.1240]} doubleClickZoom={false} zoom={7} >
    <TileLayer
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      attribution="&copy; <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
    />
    </MapContainer> 
  );
};
```

If I directly Import in Main Page then, it show
**window is undefine**

So, I decided to use dynamic from **next/dynamic**.

`MapClient`

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import CoordinateMap from "./CoordinateMap";

const Map = dynamic(() => import('@/app/_components/GlobalMap/CoordinateMap'), {
    ssr: false,
    
  })

export default Map
```

And Import it into Main Page

It solved **window is not defined** problem but it show following errors instead of that

1. Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: 

Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in

.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

2. Error: **There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.**

Answer (score 0):

I think this error happens because of the import in the second line of your **MapClient**.

This line: `import CoordinateMap from "./CoordinateMap";` interferes with the following dynamic import.

I also just posted a full example on setting up react-leaflet with NextJS 14: [React-Leaflet 4 with NextJS 14 | Working Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77978480/react-leaflet-4-with-nextjs-14-working-setup)